# MySQL: GROUP_CONCAT results with Grid Edit

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL database of tagged (keyworded) images and would like to edit the tags, *en masse*, hopefully by running something similar to the query I've created below (using GROUP-CONCAT), and then use *phpMyAdmin's* "Grid Edit" to insert new blocks of comma-delimited keywords for each image.

**tables:**

```
 'photo'              'tag'
 ---------------      ------------------
 id  | filename       photo_id  | tag
 --- |----------      --------- |-------
 1   | image1         1         | tag1
 2   | image2         1         | tag2
 3   | image3         2         | tag3
                      3         | tag1
                      3         | tag4
```

**SQL query:**

```
SELECT p.filename, group_concat(t.tag ORDER BY t.tag ASC SEPARATOR ', ')
    FROM photo p
    JOIN tag t ON p.id = t.photo_id
    GROUP BY t.photo_id
    ORDER BY p.filename
```

**query result:**

```
 filename  | tags
 --------- |----------
 image1    | tag1, tag2
 image2    | tag3
 image3    | tag1, tag4
```

The query runs fine, but has the following warning: ***This table does not contain a unique column. Grid edit, checkbox, Edit, Copy and Delete features are not available.***

**questions:**

1. Is my plan even possible with MySQL and/or *phpMyAdmin*?
2. What do I need to change in my query to enable "Grid Edit" in the output table?

Thnx!

Comment: You should edit both tables separately. Add row into `photo` table, then add new row into `tag` table.

Comment: hmm, I'm sorry for not being clear.

I'm trying to update specific records with new tags, NOT add new records (fwiw, adding image records requires entries into several other tables that also link to the 'photo' table)

Comment: I believe that @Devart's idea (which I'm inclined to agree with) is that you can't use built-in tools to modify values as a comma-separated list when they are actually stored one piece per row.

Comment: Thanks @AndriyM. I appreciate your answer even though I was really hoping for better news :)